# de n'avoir pas, de ne pas avoir

Tags: négation

In [the Louis Segond translation of Romans 12:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%2012:3&version=LSG), we find:

> je dis à chacun de vous de n'avoir pas de lui-même une trop haute opinion

Why not « de ne pas avoir » ? Is there some exception to the « ne pas + [infinitif] » rule that I don't know about?

Comment: A peu près la même chose.

Comment: Il s'agit d'un impératif dans le discours indirect, plutôt qu'un infinitif simple. Peut-être comme ça la phrase paraît plus "imperativesque"...

Comment: @RogerVadim Interesting, though I note in jlliagre's *Le bon usage* quote that it can be done without an imperative as well.

Answer (score 8):

No specific rule or exception here but ***de n'avoir pas*** is more literary and old fashioned.

[image]

Ref: Le bon usage, 14<sup>e</sup> éd., §1020, VI, b) 2°

> Si le verbe est à l'infinitif passé ou passif, le second élément se
> place avant le verbe auxiliaire dans la langue ordinaire, mais
> souvent après dans la langue soignée.
> *Je crains de **NE PAS** avoir compris* (Ac. 2003, s. v. ne).
> [...]
> *Nous nous reprochons [...] de **N**'avoir **PAS** vu ce qui nous crevait les yeux* (GIONO, Moulin de Pologne, p. 20).

The same trend is observed for other verbs with different time lags:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dans _de ne pas avoir vu_, les deux "v" rapprochés forment un allitération qui est moins présente dans _de n'avoir pas vu_. On peut utiliser _ne <verbe> pas_ pour cet effet de modulation des sonorités suivant l'effet désiré.

Answer (score 1):

Pas de différence de sens, mais *de n'avoir pas* sonne un peu bizarre ou vieillot ici.

> je dis à chacun de vous de ne pas avoir de lui-même une trop haute opinion

Passe un peu mieux de nos jours dans la langue courante.